# Can wax really improve the performance of a FM transmitter?

Tags: rf, interference, performance

Why would the use of wax improve the performance of a FM transmitter?

Consider this from the video *[How to build a FM radio transmitter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2ozDgBF6vw&t=4m14s)*, at 4 min 14 secs:

[image]

> "Theoretically this helps decrease onboard interference between the components"

---

[Wax in this case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wax#Candles) is [paraffin wax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraffin_wax) and has a relatively low [relative permittivity of 2-3](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/relative-permittivity-d_1660.html) (about the same [as many plastics](http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/general_physics/2_6/2_6_5.html)). The [resistivity of 1 x 10<sup>17</sup> Ω•m](https://www.thoughtco.com/table-of-electrical-resistivity-conductivity-608499) is higher than that of air.

I can understand [the use of wax for the mechanical stability of air coils](https://radio-receivers.blogspot.com/2016/05/regenerative-receiver-for-40-meters.html) (and thus frequency stability in some applications), but not for *"decreasing onboard interference"*.

Schematics (at 0 min 35 secs):

[image]

Comment: If this provides a higher insulation than air, then why not?  It would make it less subject to variations in humidity, etc.

Comment: Given that they don't know the conventions for drawing proper schematics, I would take anything found in this video with a large grain of salt.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: That has been my working theory since I saw it, but perhaps there is something I don't know. In the comments he states *"... wax also has signal blocking properties ..."*.

Comment: Wax is an *insulator*, so it has "signal blocking properties" in that sense.  But it's got a dielectric constant greater than air, so it'll actually increase mutual capacitance.  And while a *very* brief internet search indicates it's got pretty low dissipation, I wouldn't trust wax from some random candle.  Better RF prototyping techniques would probably gain more than slobbering wax on the thing.

Comment: My first guess is that the wax helps to avoid vibration-Induced effects. I have used wax for that purpose in RF circuits in the past. Though not in the way that video did. So I don't know.

Comment: From YouTube comments: *"My reference is a professor from the local university. Wax does indeed have signal blocking properties, but in small quantities/thin layers, its most likely not going to have an effect if any. "*

Answer (score 1):

See how crudely they strapped the conductive case of the battery to the bottom of the PCB , I would guess by "improving performance" he means "improve insulation to the bottom side solder joints" by preventing shorts yet adding stray capacitance to the battery case as a ground plane to reduce effects of crosstalk.

Don't take this concept as a good design practice nor the use of wax beyond what you already know.